# How can I make a dynamic range based on cell condition in excel 365

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, excel-365

on sheet 1 A1 I have the following formula

```
=IF(INDIRECT("'"&K5&"'!$a$9:$e$24")="","",INDIRECT("'"&K5&"'!$a$9:$e$24"))
```

This pulls a range from another sheet and keeps cells blank if they are blank.
On the other sheets I have the date listed in column A
I need the range itself (a9:e24) to be variable based on the first date found after 1/1/2024 and then add 15
So if the sheet called upon has the 1st instance of a date after 1/1/2024 in cell A10 I need the range to be (A10:E25)

I am using excel 365 free so can't use VBA and I know nothing about it anyway.
I've run into a dead end or i don't know how to ask google how to do this.
any help is appreciated

Comment: What exactly does *"...if they are blank."* mean? All 80 cells?

Comment: Well if I do not add the if(so and so="","") I get a Zero in the spots that are actually blank

Comment: Please note that using INDIRECT in a formula that you copy down multiple number of cells effects the file performance. INDIRECT is volatile and causes recaclulation of all the cells containing INDIRECT each time anything changes in the file anywhere. Is Indirect really necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Dynamically From Another Sheet

```
=LET(sheet,K5,data,"A9:E1000",date_col,1,after_date,"2024/1/1",rows_count,16,
     a,INDIRECT("'"&sheet&"'!"&data),
     b,IF(a="","",a),
     m,XMATCH(TRUE,CHOOSECOLS(b,date_col)>DATEVALUE(after_date)),
IF(ISNA(m),"",CHOOSEROWS(b,SEQUENCE(rows_count,,m))))
```

- Make sure 1000 is big enough to avoid a `#VALUE` error.
- The screenshot illustrates that the source data needs to be sorted by date i.e. `XMATCH` finds the first (top-most) 'after' date.

[image]

Comment: ok that s way beyond me...let me simplify. If i type in ="a"&"1" I get A1 returned but I need it to return whats in cell A1, If I can figure that out I can probably get the rest accomplished

Comment: It's as simple as `=A1`. Maybe you need `=INDIRECT("A"&"1")`. Have you even tried the formula?

Answer (score 0):

MATCH function find the first occurence of a value.

```
=IF(INDIRECT("'"&K5&"'!"&"A"&MATCH("1/1/2024",INDIRECT(K5&"!A:A"),0)&":E"&MATCH("1/1/2024",INDIRECT(K5&"!A:A"),0)+15)="","",INDIRECT("'"&K5&"'!"&"A"&MATCH("1/1/2024",INDIRECT(K5&"!A:A"),0)&":E"&MATCH("1/1/2024",INDIRECT(K5&"!A:A"),0)+15))
```

ADDED:

The reason that MATCH is looking for the specific type as in the lookup value. Let define a cell e.g. K6 for the date you are looking for. With this you can dynamically define the date.

```
=IF(INDIRECT("'"&K5&"'!"&"A"&MATCH(K6,INDIRECT(K5&"!A:A"),0)&":E"&MATCH(K6,INDIRECT(K5&"!A:A"),0)+15)="","",INDIRECT("'"&K5&"'!"&"A"&MATCH(K6,INDIRECT(K5&"!A:A"),0)&":E"&MATCH(K6,INDIRECT(K5&"!A:A"),0)+15))
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: This returns a REF error...I made sure there was a 1/1/2024 in column A I also dont know the exact date that will be entered which is why I want to look based on condition after 1/1/2024...I can base it on another condition if easier but date are entered in that column so thought it logical

Comment: If you get a value 45292 in the A1 cell than format the A column to Date.

Comment: its a REF error

Comment: Have you filled K5 and K6 with the sheetname and the date on the same sheet where the formula is?

Comment: Added a snapshot of the result